# Get window size

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I'm writing a Windows Universal app, and need a way to get the window's height. I have found the [Window.Bound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.window.bounds.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), but the Bound variable is non-static. Therefore, I would need to know the default Window object that is created, that is, if it exists and is public.

If I cannot access this, what is another way that I can get the window's height?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can access the corresponding `Window` using `Window.Current` and there you can get the size.
You can also try accessing the `rootFrame` and getting the size from it:

```
((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight
```

and

```
((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualWidth
```